# XML xpath Visual Studio

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, xpath

I am new to Visual Studio and getting my head around a lot of things but I'm stuck and could use some help.

I need to create a drop down list bound to a field in an XML document. I've tried configuring the data source and adding xpath expressions, but nothing shows up and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is extract from file, and say I wanted any field, i.e. `PropertyId`?

```
<PropertyDatabase>

<imageList>
  <Images>
    <ImageId>2</ImageId>
    <PropertyId>60</PropertyId>
    <ThumbUrl>propertyImages/propertyThumb60_8.jpg</ThumbUrl>
    <MainUrl>propertyImages/propertyLarge60_8.jpg</MainUrl>
    <Active />
  </Images>
  <Images>

    <ImageId>3</ImageId>
    <PropertyId>22</PropertyId>
    <ThumbUrl>propertyImages/propertyThumb22_1.jpg</ThumbUrl>
    <MainUrl>propertyImages/propertyLarge22_1.jpg</MainUrl>
    <Active />
  </Images>
```

Comment: Can  you please show the code you are using?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Linq-to-XML construct of XElement to create XML path like queries in C#.
If your file is called 'somexml.xml' then you can do the following

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("somexml.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> propertyIDs = xml.Descendants("PropertyId");
foreach(XElement propertyID in propertyIDs)
{
   //Do stuff with propertyID.Value
}
```

As you have not specified that you are using C#, here is the code in VB.Net

```
Dim xml As XElement = XElement.Load("somexml.xml")
Dim propertyIDs As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xml...<PropertyId>
For Each propertyID As XElement In propertyIDs
  'Do stuff with propertyID.Value
Next
```

Comment: thx for replies. in terms code was using - i wasnt - i was using the wizard when adding datasource in visual studio and then trying to add xpaths through there.

Comment: Ah then you should use //PropertyId

Comment: i am using c# yes thanks for that, so ive managed to add the code you suggest - sorry for my lack knowledge but now entered that how d i link it to my dropdownbox?

Comment: It depends on which platform you are using, is it WPF or Windows Forms?